# Mongodb issues connecting

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to connect in to my DATA Base using Mongoose here is my code:

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to MongoDB!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Expecting from console.log( "connected to MongoDB!"); but instead i get this :

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
server started by me
/subscribers
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.subscribers-app.nrro0mj.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.subscribers-app.nrro0mj.mongodb.net'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my router

solutions:

1. Restart your Router.
2. Manually Set your DNS Server.